# Xamarin.Forms iOS error Selector name found in current argument registers: configureAnimation:forLayer:forKey:

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, hockeyapp

I have been experiencing a problem with my Xamarin Forms application when deploying it on iOS, where it crashes suddenly while I'm using it.

I noticed that the crash happens mostly when I'm:

- working with the multiple pickers (filling some form data)
- going through pages reasonably fast (it's a questionnaire, so users are supposed to navigate forward kind of fast).

This is some portions of the Crash report I captured on HockeyApp:

```
Hardware Model:      iPad6,11
...
Parent Process:  ??? [1]

Date/Time:       2017-06-30T11:54:16Z
Launch Time:     2017-06-30T11:42:03Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 10.3.2 (14F90)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x10
Crashed Thread:  15

Application Specific Information:
Selector name found in current argument registers: configureAnimation:forLayer:forKey:
...
```

I also noticed that this crash only happens to me when using OS 10.3
I updated my Xamarin.Forms to 2.3.4.247 but nothing changed.

This is the Native stacktrace i got on visual studio 2017 when debugging on a Simulator

```
MIRE_v2.iOS                         0x0000000101b195c1 mono_handle_native_crash + 257
MIRE_v2.iOS                         0x0000000101b255c0 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 288
libsystem_platform.dylib            0x000000010ea23b3a _sigtramp + 26
???                                 0x00007fdc4f00163c 0x0 + 140584194938428
UIKit                               0x00000001025934c8 -[UIViewAnimationState actionForLayer:forKey:forView:] + 99
UIKit                               0x00000001025be87e +[UIView(Animation) _defaultUIViewActionForLayer:forKey:] + 111
UIKit                               0x0000000102d9d3e4 -[UIView(UIKitManual) actionForLayer:forKey:] + 119
QuartzCore                          0x00000001086014bc -[CALayer actionForKey:] + 437
QuartzCore                          0x00000001085fcade _ZL12actionForKeyP7CALayerPN2CA11TransactionEP8NSString + 76
QuartzCore                          0x00000001085fca6c _ZN2CA5Layer12begin_changeEPNS_11TransactionEjRP11objc_object + 140
QuartzCore                          0x00000001085fce04 _ZN2CA5Layer6setterEj12_CAValueTypePKv + 164
QuartzCore                          0x0000000108608351 -[CALayer setOpacity:] + 43
MIRE_v2.iOS                         0x0000000101cc9d79 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
???                                 0x00000001269fc8f4 0x0 + 4942973172
???                                 0x0000000126b13b4d 0x0 + 4944116557
???                                 0x00000001266a291c 0x0 + 4939458844
MIRE_v2.iOS                         0x0000000101b28525 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1301
MIRE_v2.iOS                         0x0000000101bd9b58 do_runtime_invoke + 88
MIRE_v2.iOS                         0x0000000101c1b4da start_wrapper + 538
MIRE_v2.iOS                         0x0000000101c9cdcd inner_start_thread + 189
libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010ea3593b _pthread_body + 180
libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010ea35887 _pthread_body + 0
libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010ea3508d thread_start + 13
```

And this is a little portion from the crash log of a Mac on which the simulator is running (the thread that crashed, the log is very long):

```
Thread 10 Crashed:: tid_7327
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010ea00d42 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010ea38457 pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000010e79288f abort + 127
3   com.sf.rf                       0x0000000101b19737 mono_handle_native_crash + 631 (mini-exceptions.c:2560)
4   com.sf.rf                       0x0000000101b255c0 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 288 (mini-runtime.c:2870)
5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000010ea23b3a _sigtramp + 26
6   ???                             0x00007fdc4f00163c 0 + 140584194938428
7   com.apple.UIKit                 0x00000001025934c8 -[UIViewAnimationState actionForLayer:forKey:forView:] + 99
8   com.apple.UIKit                 0x00000001025be87e +[UIView(Animation) _defaultUIViewActionForLayer:forKey:] + 111
9   com.apple.UIKit                 0x0000000102d9d3e4 -[UIView(UIKitManual) actionForLayer:forKey:] + 119
10  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00000001086014bc -[CALayer actionForKey:] + 437
11  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00000001085fcade actionForKey(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, NSString*) + 76
12  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00000001085fca6c CA::Layer::begin_change(CA::Transaction*, unsigned int, objc_object*&) + 140
13  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00000001085fce04 CA::Layer::setter(unsigned int, _CAValueType, void const*) + 164
14  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x0000000108608351 -[CALayer setOpacity:] + 43
15  com.sf.rf                       0x0000000101cc9d79 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217 (.trampolines-x86_64-objc_msgSend-post.inc:3)
16  ???                             0x00000001269fc8f4 0 + 4942973172
17  ???                             0x0000000126b13b4d 0 + 4944116557
18  ???                             0x00000001266a291c 0 + 4939458844
19  com.sf.rf                       0x0000000101b28525 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1301 (mini-runtime.c:2533)
20  com.sf.rf                       0x0000000101bd9b58 do_runtime_invoke + 88 (object.c:2860)
21  com.sf.rf                       0x0000000101c1b4da start_wrapper + 538 (threads.c:847)
22  com.sf.rf                       0x0000000101c9cdcd inner_start_thread + 189 (mono-threads.c:1172)
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010ea3593b _pthread_body + 180
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010ea35887 _pthread_start + 286
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010ea3508d thread_start + 13
```

Any ideas about the reason of this behavior? or how to deal with it?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

This is another report that might be more informative:

```
Thread 11 Crashed:: tid_9017
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000010c116acb objc_msgSend + 11
1   com.apple.UIKit                 0x0000000100d427a6 -[UIViewAnimationState animationForLayer:forKey:forView:] + 1164
2   com.apple.UIKit                 0x0000000100d434c8 -[UIViewAnimationState actionForLayer:forKey:forView:] + 99
3   com.apple.UIKit                 0x0000000100d6e87e +[UIView(Animation) _defaultUIViewActionForLayer:forKey:] + 111
4   com.apple.UIKit                 0x000000010154d3e4 -[UIView(UIKitManual) actionForLayer:forKey:] + 119
5   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x0000000106e4d4bc -[CALayer actionForKey:] + 437
6   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x0000000106e48ade actionForKey(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, NSString*) + 76
7   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x0000000106e48a6c CA::Layer::begin_change(CA::Transaction*, unsigned int, objc_object*&) + 140
8   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x0000000106e48e04 CA::Layer::setter(unsigned int, _CAValueType, void const*) + 164
9   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x0000000106e54351 -[CALayer setOpacity:] + 43
10  com.sf.rf                       0x0000000100479d79 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217 (.trampolines-x86_64-objc_msgSend-post.inc:3)
11  ???                             0x0000000125584af4 0 + 4921510644
12  ???                             0x000000012645f2fd 0 + 4937085693
13  ???                             0x0000000125373c8c 0 + 4919344268
14  com.sf.rf                       0x00000001002d8525 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1301 (mini-runtime.c:2533)
15  com.sf.rf                       0x0000000100389b58 do_runtime_invoke + 88 (object.c:2860)
16  com.sf.rf                       0x00000001003cb4da start_wrapper + 538 (threads.c:847)
17  com.sf.rf                       0x000000010044cdcd inner_start_thread + 189 (mono-threads.c:1172)
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010d1e593b _pthread_body + 180
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010d1e5887 _pthread_start + 286
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010d1e508d thread_start + 13
```

**Notice:**

I noticed also that the crash happens when I click on some buttons that have Triggers assigned to them (to change their appearance when clicked).

Comment: are you running any code on a background thread that interacts with your main UI elements?

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt I do have some Async work running in the background but it doesn't touch the UI, it's basically for data storage.

Comment: is any of the data bound to the pickers source?

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt For now all the data used in the pickers is hardcoded (statically defined)

Comment: Do you try to keep or set the selected index of the pickers when the user goes back and forth between the pages?

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt no I don't actually do that either.

Comment: I'm also using a lot of xaml Triggers to change styles, and the crash sometimes happens when I press a button that has such a trigger.

Comment: well the above crash is related to the UI elements, calayers so style changes could certainly be an issue.

Comment: It appears so, because the app also crashed when i used the pickers as described in the question, and those pickers have Triggers to change style.

Comment: I am getting the same error for my application in ios, but after updating the device to version 11 crash seems to be fixed. So this bug is only occurring in ios version below 10.3.3.